# How to Find the New Position of Unit Vectors when 3D Coordinate System Rotates

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d, coordinate-systems, rotations

Say we have the coordinate system in 3D with unit vectors at each axis (+x, -x, +y, -y, +z, -z). Next, we have a direction vector that passes through two points P1 and P2, as well as the origin. This vector rotates the 3D coordinate system to an orientation in which one of the axes (x-axis) is parallel to it (think of it like dragging the tip of one of the unit vectors to a new position in space). My goal here is to find the new position of the unit vectors after the coordinate system has been rotated. See illustration below for a clearer explanation of the problem.

Edit: Thanks to Andrei for spotting this: say that y’ and z’ can be randomly orientated by any given angle after transforming x to x’. This angle is measured from the original +y-axis

I believe a rotation matrix or quaternion is best for this type of problems; however, I'm struggling how exactly do you fit in the pieces? Really appreciate a good response

[image]

Comment: Note that your problem is not well defined. If you transform $x$ into $x'$, $y'$ and $z'$ will be in the plane perpendicular to $x'$, but they can be rotated any way you want in that plane (while still being perpendicular to each other)

Comment: Ooopppsss… i forgot to mention this part. Say that y’ and z’ can be randomly orientated by any angle after transforming x to x’. This angle is also given in the problem.

Comment: I edited the post… in addition, this angle that is used to determine the orientation of y’ and z’ is in reference with the original +y-axis

Comment: Think of the vectors as points on the unit sphere. $x' = v$, and $y',z'$ will lie on the great circle perpendicular to $v$. Your second condition is that $y'$ and $y$ form an angle of some given size $\theta$. The vectors $y'$ that make an angle $\theta$ with $y$ lie in a circle centered at $y$ of spherical radius $\theta$. Depending on the distance from $y$ to $v$, this circle may or may not intersect the great circle about $v$. If not, there is no such rotation. If so, they generally intersect in two points, so you still have two choices for $y'$.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer to this; for those who have a similar problem, what I did was to construct a [general 3D rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) using Euler angles. [You can actually determine the Euler angle based on the given vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622956/how-to-convert-direction-vector-to-euler-angles). Multiply the unit vectors on the coordinate axes with the rotation matrix to get the transformed vectors.